# js function called twice (one in document ready, one after adding new dom element) executing twice times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a function with on click method. After clicking an element with a class name, i want to do something.
i called that function in document ready. and with jquery append method a dom element is being added with that class name. and i want to call that again to work that function again. but this time function is calling twice. please check below code for understanding.

```
function function_name() {
    $('.selector').on('click',function () {
        //do something
        console.log('a')
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    function_name();
});

// after jquery append - a element with selector class is adding in dom.
// this call is inside a ajax call to bind that click with new dom element
function_name();
```

It's adding 'a' twice in console.

How to prevent this?

Comment: You are calling it twice !

Comment: i know.  but 2nd call is after ajax succes.. what about a new dom element with selector class added with ajax. how to bind that function with newly added element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: *what about a new dom element with selector class added with ajax. how to bind that function with newly added element* - use event delegation or bind to the new element directly (eg using `newElement.AppendTo(destination).on("click"...`)

Comment: event delegation example:  `$(document).on("click", ".selector", function() {...`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the one of your calls to the `function_name()` because this are calling this method twice.

The **first** time is called on your last statement of `function_name()`.

```
// after jquery append - a element with selector class is adding in dom
function_name();
```

The **second** time is called when the document is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function_name();
});
```

Comment: last function call is after a new dom element with selector class added by ajax/ jquery append to bind that click. that function call inside a ajax call. i know i called twice.  but 2nd call is after ajax succes.. what about a new dom element with selector class added with ajax. how to bind that function with newly added element?

Comment: You have to bind a click event on an element only once.